# Blog + forum CMS?

Tags: blog, cms

I need a fast, scalable PHP/MySQL solution that would have two main sections:

- a basic blogging tool, so that the site maintainers can write articles about upcoming events to be posted on the front page. A calendar should also be displayed on the front page so users know what's coming up in the next few weeks
- a forum where users can talk with each other, and also send private messages to one or more users. I like FluxBB for its speed, but I don't know if its anti-troll feature is good enough

Nice add-on's would be 1) to display the list of connected users on one side of the front page, and 2) have the calendar section let the site owners create events and let users sign up for it.

If you've found a solution that support the above, what tools did you end up choosing?

Comment: Belongs on WebMasters?

Comment: If it was re-worded to be about existing web app service providers that have these features, then it would fit here, but not so much if it's about installing yourself.

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure now... it's still a web app recommendation - not a technical question about installing them... hmm, one for a discussion on http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @overtherainbow Pro Webmasters, a Q&A site for professional webmasters, professional website operators, SEO experts public beta begins in 4 days. Please hold your question until it opens. Unfortunately your question is off topic here. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, I'll ask again at WebMasters in a few days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SquareSpace](http://www.squarespace.com) is an excellent tool. It has both of those features as well as a full content management system. Very affordable, too.

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend the following tools:

WordPress (for blog) + BuddyPress (social n/w) + bbPress (forum)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check how fast WP + BP + bbPress is.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend **Drupal** (http://drupal.org) which is a very extendable CMS.  It comes with user accounts, forums, and blogging (your basic requirements).  To find out who else is on, use the 'Who's online' block.

The calendar and event creation does not come directly out of the box but a module like GCal Events (http://drupal.org/project/gcal_events) can bring this functionality in for you.

Answer (score 0):

[vBulletin](http://www.vbulletin.com/) has both the blogging and forum functionality you're after in one solution although it's not open source and has a one-time cost of $285

Answer (score 0):

**Drupal** is my answer. A very good CMS, which has a lot of community support, and it will support what you have been asked for.

Easy to use too. If you want to see how **Drupal** works before your installation, then I highly recommend you to visit this site [DrupalGardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com). And signup a site name(of your wish), its interface built on the Drupal 7(which is the latest version). And for learning purpose you can make of its documentation.

Hope this help's you.